# Can PHP-FPM communicate with encryption between the webserver (SSL)?

Tags: php, nginx

Is it possible to set up PHP-FPM to receive/send encrypted communication with the webserver (e.g. NGINX)?  most of the documentation I've found only refers to the webserver talking to outside with SSL.

Since we have NGINX and PHP-FPM on different servers, my hope was to be able to talk between the servers with encryption.  Our webserver talk to the outside with SSL, but within the data center php and nginx communicate with over port 9000 without encryption

Comment: Maybe just create VPN between servers?

Comment: Not currently, and I don't see any discussion about it. While your concerns are valid, most people tend to run FPM locally and it will be a hard sell getting the PHP devs to implement it. That is, of course, unless you patch it in yourself and push the code upstream. Aside from that you'll need to implement the encryption at a layer outside of FPM, eg: with a VPN as suggested by kuba_ceg.